# Can VNC server be put into a read-only mode

Tags: vnc, vncserver

I want to use VNC for classroom training purposes.  so I want multiple users (students) to be able to view my shared desktop, but I only want them to view.  ie not change anything.  I looked at the VNC docs but couldn't see anything obvious.

Comment: Which VNC server? RealVNC?

Comment: Most VNC servers have obvious checkboxes for read only modes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With RealVNC, there are tick boxes under the "Inputs" tab of the server properties that you can uncheck to prevent input from clients.

- Accept pointer events from clients
- Accept keyboard events from clients
- Accepts clipboard updates from clients